# how to add class to razor form and give padding?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @Value = "Name" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @Value = "Email" })
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  }
```

how do i add a css class to this and add padding? I have the following css i wish to add to try pad it a bit

```
    .newsletterform
{
    color:black;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the class with `@class="className"` but you have to specify actionName, controllerName, FormMethod too because there is no overload of `Html.BeginForm` that supports setting only html attributes.

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
                 FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "newsletterform" }
```

You can create your own html helper, that does that for you, too.

**Update**

Here is a custom html helper does that.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static MvcForm BeginFormWithClassName(this HtmlHelper helper, string cssClassName)
    {
        string controllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        string actionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        return helper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = cssClassName });
    }
}
```

You can call the method from your view like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginFormWithClassName("newsletterform"))
{

}
```

**hope this helps**

Comment: I have tried to use this Helper adding its namespace on the <pages><namespaces> section on the web.config without any luck, did you manage to be able to use the helper globally? thanks!

Comment: You can put the extension method into the `namespace System.Web.Mvc`