# How to add class to the form built with razor html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429553/how-to-add-class-to-razor-form-and-give-padding) post, 
but still couldn't get it working. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? My code is as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", 
                        FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, 
          "Log in was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
    </p>
```

I want to add form class to this form.Please help me..

Comment: Do you have a `form` class defined in your `css`? How does the browser source look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohh..that's so silly of me. i had a id and not the class named form in my css. The above code works if you have form class defined in your css file